# Dictionary in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Does Microsoft Word have a mechanism to create a glossary (dictionary)?

Say, I would like to define a lot of therms, but want that Word automatically sorts them alphabetically, applies a style for defined therms etc.

I need also that the letters appears separately

> ***A***
>   **aback** - with the sail pressed backward against the mast by a
>   headwind.
>   **alive** - having life; living;  existing; not dead or lifeless.
>   **almost** - very nearly;
>
> ***B***
>   **bastard** - a person born of unmarried parents; an illegitimate
>   child.
>   **believe** - to have confidence in the truth, the existence, or the
>   reliability of something, although
>   without absolute proof that one is
>   right in doing so.
>   **butcher** - a retail or wholesale dealer in meat.
>   ...
>
> ***Z***
>   **Zurich** - a canton in N Switzerland. 1,118,200; 668 sq. mi.
>   (1730 sq. km).

(I use 2003, but if it is available in the latest releases I am curious to know).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a built-in feature in Word 2003 (and don't have newer versions to hand at the moment to check), but you can utilise what I think is a little-known piece of functionality in Word that allows you to sort paragraphs alphabetically.

Please note, however, that any blank lines will *all* be sorted to the top of the list - you'll need to use some form of paragraph styling on the "header" letters to create gaps above them, etc.

---

#### Let me demonstrate:

First, I've taken your example above, stuck them in an empty doc, mixed the definitions around and added a few extra "header" letters:

[image: word document showing example dictionary items and header letters jumbled up]

Next, I select all of the relevant text and then click `Table - Sort` on the menu bars. This presents me with the sort box (image below). It should already be setup as needed (check the image), so you can just hit `OK`.

[image: Word 2003 - "Sort" window]

And here's the end result, which I'm hoping is what you are after.

[image: word document showing example dictionary items and header letters correctly sorted]

Comment: this is what I actually use, but I thought there is a automatically way of doing this. If your dictionary has, say, 150 pages, you should select all the paragraphs from all that pages to sort when adding a new word...

Comment: @serhio: That's just CTRL+A. Before you say `but`, check [master documents](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-a-master-document-and-subdocuments-HP005187002.aspx)... ;)

Comment: Indeed @serhio, it isn't the best solution, but if you've got *150 pages* worth of entries, then personally I wonder if you should instead be looking for something other than Word to maintain the list in...? (not that I can make any suggestions...)

Comment: @DMA57361: Oh, no, 150 pages is not a big dictionary ) and, after, all, I am not a edition house, but just need this functionality to build a project dictionary of therms.

Comment: @TomWij: So, your suggestion is One document per letter is it?*

Comment: @serhio: No, anything that doesn't need to be sorted should be in another document if you want to use CTRL+A properly. That way you don't accidentally sort other titles and paragraphs in your document...